# How to map AWS ACCESS KEY to IAM user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have been looking information about this question, but I can't find the answerd. Do you know a simple way using AWS command line tools to map an AWS_KEY id to a specific IAM user?. The idea is to know in some old legacy EC2 boxes who is using an identity in order to revoke unused ones. For example:

```
AWS_KEY=AKAFERE12aseDesa3er11A -> belong to "user1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct one-to-one mapping to allow you to do this.  You'll probably need to call [list-users](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-users.html) to get a list of all the users associated with the AWS account, and for each user that's returned you'll need to call [list-access-keys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-access-keys.html) to get their keys and look for the one you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the only response to my question. I will try to fix it with boto and I will upload the code to my github.

Comment: any chance you could share your script?